# Periodic refresh implementation in Mvp android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mvp

I need to periodically refresh recyclerview from the server every 10 mins. Currently I am implementing MVP architecture for the app. Below are the list of approaches which I thought.

1. Should I need to use Observable.interval in the presenter to make the api calls every 10 mins ?
2. Since user should not see any updates once he is not using the app I am not using Services or broadcastrecevier.

How should I approach this problem any help will be really useful.

Thanks,
Shanthi

Answer (score 0):

Use  Timer

```
int mins = 10; // The delay in minutes
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() { 
     //perform your task
     yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}, 0, 1000 * 60 * mins);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The above implementation just refreshes the adapter but it won't make any api call. I need to make server call every 10 mins. should I use presenter call inside the run() method ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(run->{
                       you_presenter.getAllData();
                });


@override
public void showList(Data data){
     yourAdapter.addData(data);
     yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```